# Can someone tell me where's my mistake? My program gives the wrong output

Tags: c

/*3.    Write a program to calculate the net salary for 10 employees.  Use function to perform the following tasks: -
a.  Read in the gross salary for 10 employees.
b.  Calculate the net salary for each employee.
c.  Display the gross salary and net salary for each employee in tabular form.  For example: -

Gross Salary    Net Salary
2000    1820
3000    2720*/

//To calculate netsalary for 10 employees and display them

```
#include<stdio.h>

int readSalary();
int Calculatenet(int);
void displaysalary(int,int);

int main()
{

int i,salary[10],netsalary[10] ;

         for(i=0;i<10;i++)
          {

             salary[i]=readSalary(); /*for each and every element in the array, the value is entered*/

             netsalary[i]=Calculatenet(salary[i]); /*the value is passed into the function*/

             displaysalary=(salary[i],netsalary[i]); /*to display the results, the values frm both function are passed in*/
           } /*A bit confused about passing in arrays in this form. Pls correct me.*/ 

       return 0;
 }

int readSalary()
{
    int salary;
    printf("Enter your gross salary:");
    scanf("%d",&salary);
    return salary;

 }

int Calculatenet(int pay)
{
    int netsalary;
    netsalary= pay-(pay*0.1);//formula to calculate the net salary
    return netsalary;
}

 void displaysalary(int pay_, int netsalary_)
 {
    printf("Gross salary\t Net Salary\n");
    printf("%d\t %d\n",pay_,netsalary_);
}
```

Comment: what answer are you getting and what were you expecting? We can't tell you why you are getting the "wrong" output when we don't know what you expect the "right" output to be.

Comment: It's just giving the wrong answer. If I entered 900 as the salary, the netsalary should be 810 but it gives the output 809. I can't understand why.

Comment: Instead of `netsalary= pay-(pay*0.1);` try `netsalary= pay-(pay/10);`

Comment: Enable all warnings & debug info (e.g. compile with `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`). Then **use the debugger** (`gdb`). By thinking about and observing your running program (with the help of the debugger), you'll find your mistake.

Comment: @TimSeguine Thank you so much. It's giving the correct output now but why was it wrong earlier? Is it because of the decimal?

Comment: The short version is that so called floating point numbers can't represent fractions with 10 in the denominator accurately. Here is an article about the topic if you are interested in reading more: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html

Answer (score 2):

Turn your warnings on:

```
error: lvalue required as left operand of assignment
```

The problem is that you are trying to assign a value to a function.

Change

```
displaysalary = (salary[i],netsalary[i]);
```

to

```
displaysalary(salary[i],netsalary[i]);
```

On the other hand (as pointed out by Tim Seguine) you are mixing integers and floats

```
int netsalary;
netsalary= pay-(pay*0.1);//formula to calculate the net salary
```

change to

```
netsalary= pay-(pay/10);//formula to calculate the net salary
```

Comment: Thanks,fixed that yet it still returns 899 when I entered 1000. It keeps returning the wrong output, not according to the formula.

Comment: Based on the comments, the OP is experiencing floating point rounding errors for the first time.

Comment: Thank you so much! I did not know I couldn't do that! Learned something new!